# Close Button for Button - Possible?

Tags: android, tabs, horizontal-scrolling

I am making an app that has a couple list view menus that lead to a file display.  When the user opens a file (in a webview), I want to create a tab bar so that they can quickly refer back to this file even after going back through the menu and viewing a different file.  I planned on creating a fragment activity that housed a horiz scroll view that housed buttons that referenced the file that they viewed.  Then, when they move on to a different file, they can just hit the tab and return to the file referenced on the tab.

Couple things:
-the tab bar, once created, needs to persist across activities until closed by the user
-the tab bar needs to refresh itself every time the user opens a new file
-it would be really nice to have a little close button (like the red x in the corner in apple stuff) on the tab buttons, so that the user can close individual tabs.

Is this possible?

any suggestions, tips, etc ?

Is android's built in tabs a better way to go than horiz scroll view with buttons?

thanks in advance